# What is the proper study of composition and arrangement?

Tags: theory, composition

I have been composing and arranging on my own for about 10 months now, i am confident that they sound good but i am not sure, how good, how to make them better and if taking the proper course will make them better or if it is a waste of resources.

Comment: Use the site a bit, and when your reputation rises a little, you can post compositions in the chat room to get feedback.

Comment: Welcome! This is kind of too broad a question to answer; see [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to get targeted, factual answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). As Aaron suggests, we have a chat room specifically for sharing work. In the meantime, if you have a specific question about a certain problem or bit of music, feel free to edit to focus on that.

Answer (score 0):

Music is impossible to compose using just schemes. I mean it's technically possible, but unfeasible to write music that is sincere and elicits warm feedback from the other person's heart using only theory and schemes.

Of course, the best way is if you're fluent in music theory, but it's hardly enough.
You can't describe all music with "math".

There's something much more important behind all of that.

If it sounds good, truly and sincere sends a message about what's in your heart, and it's all about good things, not containing anything even remotely close to something sinful and vice, that's how it has to be!

Don't overthink, especially if you feel it's not a good moment for doing so.

P.S. Flee from bad things in music and music industry, related to any sin or not innocent even a bit, avoid them no matter what by any means, they'll brazenly bait you but then that will hurt sooooooo much, it will be such an unbearable pain and inner devastation you probably can't even imagine now. I know what I'm talking about.
Don't write music for fame, it makes ZERO sense, create music for people you love.
Even for everyone, even for the people you don't know.

Don't overthink like "I want to write a cool melody, wanna make it hard, deeply detailed, so...how do I make a complicated accompaniment?..." that's a FAIL.

Just write simply and sincerely what's in your heart, not "I want to compose just to compose".